# Is there any Method distinguishes between array and dictionary in Swift?

Tags: swift

I tried to make weather app with JSON.

When I get data from the web sources, always there are array and dictionary are mixed in data.

Now I use `if` to ensure which one has key value, but it is much more convenient if there was method.

I use Swift to make the app.

Comment: Dealing with JSON in Swift is cumbersome. Try some other framework like SwiftyJson: https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

Answer (score 0):

given json:

```
{ id: 1234, name: "foo", list: ["bar", "bazz"], rate: 0.4}
```

you can access it like this:

```
var json:AnyObject = ... //usually passed from a rest service
var id = json["id"] as? Int //access the id attribute of the json root object
var array:[AnyObject] = json["list"] as? AnyObject[]
if let unwrappedArray = array { //check & assign for nil value
    //access the array values
    var bar = uwrappedArray[0] as String?
}
```